# Is there a full list of FN-key mappings for the MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I am looking for a document that would specify how can I produce strokes like the ones below on a MacBook Pro keyboard.

- Insert
- Numpad Plus
- Numpad Minus
- ...

Answer (score -1):

So far this seems to be the most complete list:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5636

Comment: great link, how do you send a numpad Plus though?